# Trying to create relation in Navicat

Tags: mysql

I was dumb and created a year ago tables for a customer. Now I know better and should have used relations. Now I am trying to create them in Navicat. Executing:

```
ALTER TABLE geerdink_new.dossier 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dossier_klant_1 
    FOREIGN KEY (dossierKlantID) 
    REFERENCES geerdink_new.klant (klantID)
```

I am getting some errors:

> [Msg] Failed - Error on Foreign Key fk_dossier_klant_1 - 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`geerdink_new`.`#sql-420_51`, CONSTRAINT `fk_dossier_klant_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dossierKlantID`) REFERENCES `klant` (`klantID`))

How am I able to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces this error?

Comment: Executing - ALTER TABLE `geerdink_new`.`dossier` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_dossier_klant_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dossierKlantID`) REFERENCES `geerdink_new`.`klant` (`klantID`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Navicat error, but a MySQL error. Something is not matching properly when you're trying to create your constraint, likely:

1) The column definitions are not identical (for instance one is an unsigned integer, and the other  is a signed integer)

2) There are values in one column that do not correspond with values in the column you're creating a relationship with.

edit: Try this query:

```
SELECT klantID FROM klant LEFT JOIN geerdink_new ON geerdink_new.dossierKlantId = klant.klantID WHERE dossierKlantId IS NULL;
```

Comment: After checking column datatypes, you can run this `SELECT * FROM geerdink_new.dossier AS d WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM geerdink_new.klant AS k WHERE k.klantID = d.dossierKlantID);` to find rows in `dossier` that have no related row in `klant`.

Comment: If they are `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` columns, their character sets and collations must be the same, too.